# clojure combinatorics - do not treat input list as multiset

Tags: python, clojure, combinations

For combinatorics problems, I've been using `clojure.math.combinatorics`, which is great, however I was a little surprised by the below result the first time I encountered it (despite being clearly spelled out in the docs).

Clojure "intelligently handles duplicates" treating the input collection as a multiset:

```
(combo/combinations [1 1 1 2 2] 3)
=> ((1 1 1) (1 1 2) (1 2 2))
```

Again, this is well documented and intended behavior, it just surprised me coming from a python background where combinations are treated as they are actually represented in the input collection, rather than treated as a multiset.

```
list(itertools.combinations([1,1,1,2,2],3))
=> [(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 2), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 2)]
```

I figured there was probably either a different function, or parameter that could be supplied to get the latter behavior, but it doesn't appear to be the case.

I am just wondering if there is another canonical library that does this, or if it's a "roll your own" situation - which is where my initial research is leading me.  I don't think I'd write the functions nearly as elegant as what's in the combinatorics library so I was really hoping there were existing efficient implementations of nice, lazy behavior, but with the standard semantics shown in the python example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a quick and dirty workaround, you can just make the elements unique before you pass them to `combo/combinations`. This adds some overhead, but the functions in math.combinatorics are pretty optimized, so that might not be a problem.

```
(ns foo.core
  (:require
   [clojure.math.combinatorics :as combo]))

(defn indexed [coll] ;; also found in the medley library
  (map-indexed vector coll))

(defn un-indexed [coll]
  (map second coll))

(defn python-combinations [coll n]
  (map un-indexed (combo/combinations (indexed coll) n)))

(comment

  (python-combinations [1 1 1 2 2] 3)
  ;;=> ((1 1 1) (1 1 2) (1 1 2) (1 1 2) (1 1 2) (1 2 2) (1 1 2) ...)
  )
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of this :/  I think the overhead is probably not going to be much of an issue compared to the overhead involved in actually creating the combinations.  Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

It's funny, just last week I stumbled across this same behavior in `clojure.math.combinatorics`.  Here is a different workaround, where we simply compute the combinations of all of the ***indexes*** of the values:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.test )
  (:require
    [tupelo.core :as t]
    [clojure.math.combinatorics :as combo] ))
(t/refer-tupelo)

(defn python-combinations [coll n]
  (let [values     (vec coll)
        idxs       (range (count values))
        idx-combos (combo/combinations idxs n)
        combos     (forv [idx-combo idx-combos]
                     (mapv #(nth values %) idx-combo))]
    combos))

(dotest
  (is= (python-combinations [1 1 1 2 2] 3)
    [[1 1 1] [1 1 2] [1 1 2] [1 1 2] [1 1 2]
     [1 2 2] [1 1 2] [1 1 2] [1 2 2] [1 2 2]] ))
```

Comment: Thanks - i think this is pretty similar to what @madstap did, although you explicitly take combinations of indices and then index into values afterwards.  Funny we both encountered this - I guess the library code is trying to be helpful but personally I find it confusing.  Particularly since if you call the corresponding `count-combinations` with duplicates in the list, it will give you the traditional answer (e.g. 10 vs 3 in the example above).  So it knows to handle the special case of duplicates when you count items, but when you ask for the collection back it helps you out by removing dups

Comment: @Solaxun I think that mismatch between `combinations` and `count-combinations` is very non-intuitive. It should be one or the other. Maybe open an issue about it? It should at least be mentioned as a gotcha in the docs, in my opinion.

Comment: @madstap Agree - I would much prefer the default behavior be to *not* help out by removing dups, like pretty much all other implementations.  We can always just call set on the result if that is what we want.  Or at least provide a flag `:duplicates false` or something similar.

Comment: @AlanThompson
1/3
I think that calling `combo/combinations` on just the indices is neat, it probably doesn't make a whole lot of difference, but I can imagine that being more efficient than my solution (needs becnhmarking, ofc, if you really care about presumably small differences like that). He asked for a lazy solution, though, why don't you just use `for` instead of `forv`?

Actually what's the whole tupelo stuff about?!

Comment: 2/3
1. You `:use` a two different namespaces, which is [considered non-idiomatic](https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide#prefer-require-over-use) (as a reader I have to go looking for where does this fn come from) and doesn't work in cljs.

2. There's this strange thing `refer-tupelo` which does what exactly?

3. Without linking to tupelo, so to get the answer to work I need to go googling.

4. At the cost of dragging in [all these dependencies](https://imgur.com/O0s20la)

5. Without [disclosing that it is your library](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302)

Comment: 3/3
And all this with no explanation and no apparent reason except for making the whole thing non-lazy. I won't give a -1 now as it might be considered bad form when I have another answer to the same question, and in any case everyone deserves a chance, but I really think that your [constant pushing](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tupelo+user%3AAlanThompson) of tupelo is detracting from the general quality of answers about clojure on this site.

Comment: @madstap I don't think it's bad form to downvote for these reasons. As I've told Alan before I often downvote his answers because while they always have some useful content the amount of tupelo nonsense greatly detracts from their usefulness, and the downvote button is clearly labeled "not useful". Of course the answers without tupelo are almost always worth an upvote, because Alan does indeed know good approaches to many Clojure problems.

Comment: -1 because of the Tupelo thing. If you’re promoting a library, please don’t do it in this answer, as I don’t see you using your library anywhere in the answer at all.

Comment: Please also note that the OP liked the answer, which is what matters most to me.